# Changing the order of keys in a list of dictionaries with TypeError?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
dicts = [{'date':2018, 'target':'usd'}, {'date':2020, 'target':'eur'}, {'date':2019, 'target':'eur'}]
```

I want to rearrange the order of the keys like this:

```
[{'target':'usd','date':2018}, { 'target':'eur','date':2020}, {'target':'eur',date':2019}]
```

I have tried this but am getting an error in my python 3.9:

```
key_order = [ 'target', 'date']
dicts = {k : dicts[k] for k in key_order}
dicts

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dicts` is a list, not a dictionary. as the error message states.

this may work:

```
dicts = [{k: dct[k] for k in key_order} for dct in dicts]
```

you need the dict-comprehension inside a list-comprehension.

you need at least python 3.6 for this to work. before that version dicts werde not insertion-ordered.

Comment: yes, I have python 3.9.7. added in the question. thank you v much.